# Sorting the Datagridcolumn using ObservationCollection class on headerclicking WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I am trying to sort the datagrid columns that has dynamically rows generation using ObservableCollection class. Whaqt I want is, when I click on the the Header then the rows should be sort in asecending and descending on another clicking. Here I used the pagination concept So I tried using SortMemberPath and CanUserSort tags, but it only sorts the rows of a single page but I want to sort all the binded rows using ObservableCollection class that will sort all the rows on every pages on a single click on header.

```
<DataGrid>  
<DataGrid.Resources />
 <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Header" CanUserSort="True" >
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn> 
</DataGrid>
```

This is able to sort only one page rows not entire collection of rows. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*Here I used the pagination concept*": how? show what you did in your question, thanks

Comment: meaning there are different pages and each page contains 10 records. So only 10 records are able to sort when I click on the header. Then when I move to the next page again I can sort another 10 records. So, what I want is when I click on the header all the 20 records are able to sort at once.

Comment: Meaning that you have to show the relevant code if you're looking for help here